# soft-macros are empty in csv parser

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I'm trying to parse log messages that are received from a udp port and insert them into a MYSQL database. My destination in my syslog-ng.conf file is as follows:

```
source syslog_udp {
    udp(port(<port num>) flags(no-parse));
};
```

The parser I have written is as follows:

```
parser p_logparser{
    csv-parser(columns("<column1>", "<column2>", ...)
    flags(strip-whitespace)
    delimiters(",")
    template("${<column1}\n")
    );
};
```

I am also using a filter to "discard" a certain part of the log message:

```
filter log_filter { not (match("<string>") and match("<string>"));};
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to write the contents of "column1" into a MYSQL database, but for testing purposes I am currently writing to a file:

```
destination d_file {
            file("<path>/${ISODATE}" template("Testing : ${column1}"));
};
log {
            source(syslog_udp);
            parser(p_logparser);
            filter(log_filter);
            destination(d_file);
};
```

However, when I open the file that's described in d_file, all I can see is "Testing : " and the contents of column1 aren't actually there. I have a feeling it is because my parser is not creating the soft macros properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "template" line in your parser. This option specifies which part of the log message you want to parse with the CSV-parser, and at this point that's probably the default (${MESSAGE}).